# Sitecore 9 wffm forms custom css file not accessible

Tags: wffm

I am using Sitecore wffm forms on web page. I needed to use a custom CSS file for the form, so I am following https://sitecoregenie.wordpress.com/2018/08/06/add-a-custom-css-file-for-wffm/ to add custom CSS file for the form and for doing that new CSS file should be added in folder `\sitecore modules\Shell\Web Forms for Marketers\Themes\`.

Now, when I navigate to the web page to see Sitecore WFFM form, the custom CSS file is not applied to the web page. When I go to view source of the page, I see that the CSS file is being added but when I click on it I am being navigated to the Sitecore login page. Is there a way to bypass the Sitecore login for that CSS file in the Sitecore modules folder so that the page loads the CSS file and applies it to my form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bypass the sitecore login by adding following location section in the web.config file which will bypass the authorization of the css and js files placed in the specific folder.

```
<configuration>
 <location path="sitecore modules/Shell/Web Forms for Marketers/Themes">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>
</configuration>
```